# How can I draw a dashed line on a scatter plot in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

With Chartjs, I'd like to draw dashed lines on a scatter plot.
I'm using the scatter plot and not the line plot because I need to display constant-time ticks on my x axis (my data has varying sampling frequency)

I have some code that displays a line on the scatter plot, but the border dash property is not recognized

```
const datasets = [{
    data: [{ x: 0, y: 1,36 }, { x:2, y: 2,47 } ...],
    borderColor: #fff,
    label: "24h moving average",
    showLine: true,
    borderDash: [5, 5] // Not working
}]
```

Is it possible to do this in chartjs ?

Comment: Does **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/t9fuwzjg/3/)** help?

Comment: In Chart.js, you can create dashed lines on a scatter plot using the borderDash property. To ensure it works: Use Chart.js version 2.x or later. Set showLine to true. If the dashed line doesn't appear, check your dataset structure and browser console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:(requires ***version 2.x or higher***):

```js
const datasets = [{
      data: // Your data,
      borderColor: '#f00',
      label: "24h moving average",
      showLine: true,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderDash: [5, 5]
    }];

    // ..ctx

    const myScatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        datasets: datasets
      },
      options: {
        // ...options
      }
    });
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mandy8055/w5ot046s/)***